# Not able to understand what this C function does

Tags: c, pointers

I have seen this piece of code several times but am unable to understand what it does

```
inline char nc()
{
    static char buf[100000], *L = buf, *R = buf;
    return L == R && (R = (L = buf) + fread(buf, 1, 100000, stdin), L == R) ? EOF : *L++;
}
```

The condition `L==R` should always be true , right? since both the pointers point to the same variable. I cant understand what the second part of the condition checks. Could someone please help me out?

Comment: This function is essentially a fancy `getchar()` that buffers the input.

Comment: Fancy, schmanzy, I would say convoluted, obfuscated, obtuse, but sure, let's go with fancy :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All the variables are declared as `static` which means that they keep their value from the previous function call. The initializations `=buf` are only run the first time the function is called. It's basically the same thing as if you declared those variables as globals and initialized them before the first function call. Of course with the difference that globals can be accessed from anywhere in the code.

Let's disassemble the second line a bit. It can be rewritten like this:

```
char ret;
if(L == R && 
   R = (L = buf) + fread(buf, 1, 100000, stdin), L == R) {
       ret = EOF;
} else {
    ret=*L; // Return the character read
    L++;    // Advance to next character in the buffer
}
return ret;
```

A bit clearer, but still a bit clunky. The second condition `R = (L = buf) + fread(buf, 1, 100000, stdin), L == R)` is not very clear. It can be rewritten like this:

```
L = buf;
int noCharactersRead = fread(buf, 1, 100000, stdin);
R = L + noCharactersRead;
if(L == R)  // If no characters have been read
    ret = EOF;
```

So the complete refactored code (with some extra refactoring) will be

```
char nc()
{
#define BUFSIZE 100000
    static char buf[BUFSIZE], *L = buf, *R = buf;
    if(L == R) { // If buffer is empty
        L = buf; // Reset L to beginning of buffer

        // Read next character from stdin, put it in the buffer
        // and check if read was successful
        int noCharactersRead = fread(buf, 1, BUFSIZE, stdin);

        // Return EOF on read failure
        if(noCharactersRead == 0)
            return EOF;

        // Advance R one step if a character was read
        R = L + noCharactersRead;

    } 

    // If the buffer was not empty, or if the buffer was empty and we
    // successfully read a new character into the buffer, return the next
    // character in the buffer and advance L
    return *L++; 
}
```

I removed the `inline` because the function contains static variables. An alternative would be to declare the function as `static inline`.

It is essentially a buffered version of `getchar()` function, but written in a very unreadable way. Do also note that it has very little protection for buffer overflow. It basically relies on the buffer being big enough to not cause any issues. A way to solve this would be changing the call to `fread` to `fread(buf, 1, BUFSIZE - (R-L), stdin)`

Answer (score 5):

This is basically equivalent of:

```
char buf[100000];
char* L = buf;
char* R = buf;

char non_fancy_getchar()
{
    if (L == R) {
        /* reset pointers and try to read stdin again */
        L = buf;
        R = L + fread(buf, 1, sizeof(buf), stdin);
    }

    /* return next char or EOF */
    return (L == R) ? EOF : *L++;
}
```

Comment: The most clear explanation here, even though static and global variables are not really the same :-) Maybe add a small note about that

Answer (score 5):

It is a broken function written by somebody who thought they were clever.

The objects `buf`, `L`, and `R` are defined with `static`, they they exist for the duration of program execution and are initialized when execution begins. They keep their values between calls to the function.

Nominally, the function returns either a character (`*L++`) or `EOF`. But the return type is `char`, which should not be used by routines returning `EOF`. `EOF` is specified to be an `int` value and either is not `char` value, overlaps a `char` value (which is not desired because then they cannot be distinguished—the routine ought to be using `unsigned char` for `buf`), or raises other issues when converted to a `char` value (the conversion will signal or will overlap with a `char` value).

The intent appears to be that `L` (for “Left”) points to the left side of characters that have been read into the buffer and not yet consumed, and `R` points to the right side (end) of characters that have been read into the buffer. When `L` equals `R`, the buffer is empty, and more characters should be read into it.

When `L` (for “Left”) and `R` (for “Right”) are equal, the right operand of the `&&` is evaluated. We can rewrite it:

```
(R = (L=buf) + fread(buf,1,100000,stdin), L==R)
    ? EOF
    : *L++;
```

This resets `L` to the start of the buffer and then attempts to read 10000 characters. The number of characters actually read is added to `L` and then assigned to `R`. So `L` points to the start of the newly read characters (at the beginning of `buf`), and `R` points to the end (one past the last character read).

After this, the comma operator effectively causes `L==R` to be used as the controlling value for `? :`. If no characters were read, `L` equals `R`, and the routine attempts to return `EOF` (but may fail as explained above). If characters were read, `*L++` returns the first character and increments `L` to point to the next character.

On subsequent calls when there are characters in the buffer, the left operand of the `&&`, `L==R`, is false, so right operand is not evaluated. The expression then looks like `false && (DoesNotMatter) ? EOF : *L++`. Since the result of the `&&` is false, `*L++` returns the next character in the buffer and advances `L`. As calls continue, eventually `L` will equal `R`, and the buffer will be empty, causing new data to be read.

Comment: in your last statement when L==R is false, the second operand of the && operator wont be evaluated at all because of short-circuit evaluation so there is no need to check the L==R after the comma operator...the entire second operand should be DoesNotMatter :D

Comment: isn't it X && ( Y , Z ) ?

Comment: But doesn't the bracket around the second && operand also include the comma operator ..(R = (L = buf) + fread(buf, 1, 100000, stdin), L == R) ?

Comment: @physics123: Yes, I missed that. Thanks. I did not understand you were saying I had shown the parenthesis in the wrong place and thought you were saying the precedence affected the comma operator. I have edited the answer to correct it.

Answer (score 3):

[This function is essentially a fancy `getchar()` that buffers the input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56313965/not-able-to-understand-what-this-c-function-does#comment99237279_56313965). The static declaration part is really run once.
Let's break it down. `buf` is the buffer. `L` and `R` probably stand for left and right. So they point to the beginning and ending of the buffer. If `L == R` is false, we still have something in the buffer, so the second condition is not evaluated, and we get a character from the buffer, and increase the left pointer. If `L == R` is true, the second part is evaluated which tries to fill the buffer with `L` pointing to the very beginning and `R` pointing to `L` plus the number of characters read from `stdin`. The comma operator means the first part is ignored and we evaluate `L == R` again, which is false if we read some characters, so we return the first one, but is true if we didn't read anything, so we return `EOF` which is really not guaranteed to be representable with a char. The return type should probably be an `int`.

Here is a more readable version (untested):

```
inline int nc() // notice the return type
{
    static char buf[100000];      // run only once
    static char *beg = buf; // L  // run only once
    static char *end = buf; // R  // run only once

    if (beg != end)  // If buffer is not empty
    {
      return *beg++; // return a character
    }
    beg = buf;
    // if the buffer is empty, try to read into it
    end = buf + fread(buf, 1, 100000, stdin);
    if (beg != end)
    {
      return *beg++;
    }
    // If reading failed, return EOF
    return EOF;
}
```